# Calculating number of students who don't study any language

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

> According to a survey of 100 students, there are 40 students studying
>   English, 30  studying French, and 25 studying Spanish.   Inaddition, 8
>   students are studying English  and French, 6 are studying English and
>   Spanish, 5 are studying French and Spanish, and  22 are not studying
>   any of the three languages.   Which of the following is the number  of
>   students studying all three languages?

I would love to know is there any particular method to solve this kind of math?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Have you seen inclusion-exclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sets

$E$ : students studying English

$F$ : students studying French

$S$ : students studying Spanish

For this kind of question you can use the formula:

$$
n(E \cup F \cup S) = n(E) + n(F) + n(S) - n(E \cap F) - n(E \cap S) - n(F \cap S) + n(E \cap F \cap S)
$$

where $n(E)$ indicates the number of elements of $E$. So
\begin{align*}
&n(E \cup F \cup S) = 100 - 22 = 78\\
&n(E) = 40\\
&n(F) = 30\\
&n(S) = 25 \\
&n(E \cap F) = 8\\
&n(E \cap S) = 6\\
&n(F \cap S) = 5\\
\end{align*}

You can use this same method for similar questions.

Comment: Clear as crystal! Thanks alot Barbosa!